# General equation of cylinder surface

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

According to the definition "**A cylinder is a surface that consists of all lines (called rulings) that are parallel to a given line and pass through a given plane curve.**
" I'm curious about the general equation of cylinder . I mean finding the equation by using the line and plane curve .

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the plane curve is given by the equation $f(x,y) = 0$, and the line is parallel to $\vec v = \left<a,b,c\right>$.  Given a point $P= (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ in space, we need to:

1. Trace the line through $P$ parallel to $\vec v$;
2. Find the point $Q$ of intersection of that line with the $xy$-plane;
3. Decide if $Q$ is on the curve. If it is, $P$ is on the cylinder.

Let the coordinates of $Q$ be $(x_0,y_0,0)$.  The parametric equations for the line are
\begin{align*}
    x &= x_1 + at \\
    y &= y_1 + bt \\
    z &= z_1 + ct
\end{align*}
If $x=x_0$, $y=y_0$, and $z=0$, we can solve
\begin{align*}
    x_0 &= x_1 - \frac{a}{c}z_1 \\
    y_0 &= y_1 - \frac{b}{c}z_1
\end{align*}
[If $c=0$, the vector is parallel to the $xy$-plane and we won't get a cylinder at all.]  This point is on the curve if $f(x_0,y_0) = 0$.  Replacing the point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ with a varying point $(x,y,z)$, the equation for the cylinder is
$$
    f\left(x-\frac{a}{c}z,y-\frac{b}{c}z\right) = 0
$$

Comment: Very nice but I think it doesn't include all of the possibilities . For example consider when the surface is rotated .

Comment: @S.H.W Is that still a cylinder then?

Comment: Yes , for example consider this surface : https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Milos_Sramek/publication/4112379/figure/fig6/AS:668401420738566@1536370725273/a-Cylinder-along-the-z-axis-rotated-with-angles-a-and-b-around-the-x-axis-and-y-axis.ppm

Comment: Oh I see.  That wasn't part of the original post.  Perhaps you mean to change *plane curve* to *space curve*?  But even in the case of the picture you gave, I think it still intersects the horizontal plane in a curve (an ellipse instead of a circle, as suggested by the figure)

Comment: I mean the plane curve can be placed on the planes other than $xy$ plane .

Comment: Another example is $y^2 + z^2 = 1$ .

Comment: I upvoted because it is a nice answer for the cases it covers.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Do you have any idea for general case ?

Answer (score 1):

This definition is for a generalized cylinder, so it does not necessarily look like this:

[image]

However, to see this standard cylinder as an example of the definition you have, we could take the plane curve to be a circle and the line of parallel to be perpendicular to the plane we have parameterized the circle in.

So for example, $r(t) = (cos(t), sin(t),0)$ for $t \in [0,2\pi)$ is a unit circle in the plane $z = 0$ and the line of parallel is $s(t) = (0,0,t)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The cylinder determined by this set up, according to your definition, would correspond to a cylinder like the one pictured above.

The flexibility your definition is allowing is that we don't have to use a circle for the plane curve, we don't have to embed the plane curve in the plane $z = 0$, and we don't have to choose the 'rulings' (lines) to be perpendicular to the plane. So you could get something more like this:

[image]

My art skills are lacking.

Also, depending on how they defined ‘plane curve’, you don’t even have to use a closed loop for the plane curve - you could have used a straight line, or a parabola, which would be even less similar to a usual cylinder.

Let us see if we can get a general sort of equation for these objects. If we restrict for now to "cylinders" that are going to live in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then if our plane curve is given by some parameterization $r(t)$ and the line of parallel is given by some $s(t) = p_1 + t\cdot p_2$ where $p_1, p_2$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then according to your definition, to get the cylinder we want to make lines going through the plane curve, parallel to $s(t)$.

Our cylinder parameterization could look something like

$c(u,v) = r(u) + v \cdot p_2$.

Why is that? See if you can figure it out. What happens when the parameter $v = 0$? (it traces out the plane curve). What happens when you fix $u$ and let $v$ vary? (it traces out lines going through a point on the plane curve). Maybe go on 3D graphing software and plug this in for specific $r(t)$ plane curves and lines $s(t)$. Mac computers come with 3D graphing software.

Playing around with parameterizations is fun. When I started writing this answer I actually didn't know what the equation would be, but with practice you learn how to tinker with these things and can usually figure out what you want.

Comment: How we can find the general equation ?

Comment: Hey! Sorry, I just noticed finding the equation is the crux of your question. Editing now

Comment: Thanks a lot , is it possible to write the implicit equation in general instead of parametric equation ?

Comment: You mean like how for a standard cylinder in $/matchbox{R}^3$ you could write it as the set of points satisfying $x^2 + y^2 + 0z = 1$ ? I think for a general cylinders that might not be feasible. You could probably do it for any plane curve as long as you are embedding it in the plane $z=0$ and as long as you want the rulings to be perpendicular$. What is the context for this math you are doing?

Comment: Okay , I was studying the quadric surfaces and then encountered the cylinder definition . It is really interesting to be able to determining the shape of surface using the general quadric equation .

Comment: Hmm, in your specific applications and context there may be theorems that apply (e.g implicit function theorem) to say when the surface can be written implicitly. If you add more information (like what book you are working out of) and add tags to your question someone might be able to give a better answer

Comment: Okay , thanks for your guidance .

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the approaches you can have is to start from the equation of a special cylinder (like one having a radius of 1 parralel to the z-axis), and apply a rotation, an homothety and a translation on the x, y and z.

The equation of this original cylinder is : (x - a)<sup>2</sup> + (y - b)<sup>2</sup> = 1.

Here, a and b are the coordinates of the intersection of the axis of the cylinder with the xy plane. An example of rotation (around the x axis) in the 3-space is given by the matrix :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) \\
0 & sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Apply it on the coordinates of the equation and you'll get the equation for a new rotated cylinder, rotated of an angle $\theta$ from the x-axis :

$$(x - a)^2 + (cos(\theta) y - sin(\theta) z - b)^2 = 1$$

After that, you can try another rotation, around the z-axis this time, with matrix :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\phi) & -sin(\phi) & 0 \\
sin(\phi) & cos(\phi) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

This gives :

$$(cos(\phi) x - sin(\phi) y - a)^2 + (cos(\theta) (cos(\phi) y + sin(\phi) x) - sin(\theta) z - b)^2 = 1$$

Then, to make the cylinder the scale you want, you can use the transformation given by :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}$$

This gives :

$$(cos(\phi) \lambda x - sin(\phi) \lambda y - a)^2 + (cos(\theta) (cos(\phi)\lambda  y + sin(\phi) \lambda x) - sin(\theta) \lambda z - b)^2 = 1$$

Or, more simply :

$$(cos(\phi) x - sin(\phi) y - a)^2 + (cos(\theta) (cos(\phi) y + sin(\phi) x) - sin(\theta) z - b/\lambda)^2 = 1/\lambda^2$$

A second approach, which I find shorter, is to use the formula for the distance between a line and a point. The distance between the line of vector $\vec{u}$ passing by $B$ and a point $A$ is given by :

$$d^2(A,B,\vec{u}) = \frac{\left\lVert{\vec{AB} \wedge \vec{u}}\right\rVert^2}{\left\lVert{\vec{u}}\right\rVert^2}$$.

It remains to write $d^2(A,B,\vec{u}) = r^2$ and to express it in terms of x, y and z (the coordinates of A), and this will give an algebraic equation for the cylinder.

Comment: According to the definition it should pass through a given plane curve . So the circle is not generally true .

Comment: I like this solution! There are a couple of typos in the passages after the second matrix rotation; cos(θ)(cos(ϕ)+sin(ϕ)x)y should be instead cos(θ)(cos(ϕ)y+sin(ϕ)x); that typo propagates to the scaling. Finally the right-hand side of the final equation should be 1/λ square.